# How do I grant users the ability to install windows services?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-service, permissions

I'd like to be able to allow the development team to install services on a Win2003 server. They can already connect via RDP/FTP with limited accounts but I'd like to be able to grant installation privileges.

How do I do that without granting admin rights?

(The services are created using the .NET framework so we're installing with C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\installutil.exe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delegated permission to install services is going to be a little bit tough. There is a "SC_MANAGER_CREATE_SERVICE" right that can be granted to users on the service control manager (SCM) object in the global object manager.

In Windows versions up to Windows Server 2003, the rights could not be changed on the SCM. Starting in W2K3 SP1, you could change the rights on the SCM.

The API to change the security is *SetServiceObjectSecurity*, and more information is available here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379589(VS.85).aspx

Some more reference re: the rights that can be granted to the SCM and the default DACL set on the SCM is available here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685981(VS.85).aspx

In short, there's no way to do this w/o writing code. There's no magic registry setting, etc. If you can get somebody to write the code for you, though, it's totally feasible.

Comment: Great, thanks. The server is SP2 and I can write the code so this may be the way forward.

Answer (score 3):

I think the bigger problem is letting the dev team access a server they don't administer.  Rather than trying to grant the rights to the users (SC_MANAGER_CREATE_SERVICE) think really hard about giving them their own box- even just a VM to test on, once they say it's ready an actual admin should install the services into the production system.

Comment: The services will be tested both on the dev's box and in VMs by the time they get to production. I'm confident enough in the dev team to grant them admin access but I'm going for least privilege. The actual admin is me but I'd like to delegate this function.

Answer (score 0):

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=288129 has some info on managing services, but I don't think this can be extended to include creating arbitrary services without some major security changes on your server.

If you create a service or services then grant access as described in the knowledge base, your developers can stop the service and copy in new binaries, so they can develop/debug services even if you have to create them in the first place.

Personally I restrict our developers to a test server and grant them administrator access. The little darlings don't get access to my live servers without first convincing me their stuff is working!

JR

Comment: That's granting users rights to manage existing services, which is different than what the poster is looking for. The poster is looking for rights being granted on the service control manager object itself. It would be a bit of a "hack" to "pre-create" several services and have the users substitute in their binaries, but I suppose you could do that.

Comment: Using "pre-created" services is all I could come up with. I have to say it seems a slightly odd question. If developers need to create services this sounds like a development environment. Would you let developers loose on your live servers? I think the best answer might be to give the developers their own server!

Comment: I agree. There is a built-in mechanism for doing this, but it's really not something that I'd advise in practice. I'm one of those "Answer the question literally" kind of people, for the most part. I'd agree, though, that it's compromising the production server's integrity to let developers go wild on them creating services. That's a really major change to be allowing unprivileged accounts to perform.