# Minimal permissions needed to install Service under Windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7, permissions, windows-service

What are the minimal permissions that IT would have to grant me in order to allow me to install a service under Windows 7?

Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Administrators.

The Power Users group only has access to start/stop existing services, but explicitly can not install new services.

Comment: It's worth noting that this behaviour *can* be changed in W2K3 SP1 and newer OS's. See my answer here for some details: http://serverfault.com/questions/37721/how-do-i-grant-users-the-ability-to-install-windows-services/37730#37730